# Angular Material: display matError with matTooltip

Tags: angular-material, tooltip, validationerror

I want to display the validation error with inside a bubble under the input, which is visible as long as the user focuses the element.
Obviously this is not an easy task, and I gave up on my first try to do this only with CSS (cannot make it overly certain elements, what if the element is at the end of the page etc.).

So I went back to the angular page and found the matTooltip, which behaves exactly as I want. (on top of other element, changes position when at the end of the page etc.) :) However I'm stuck on how to best combine those two.

matError is tightly coupled with matFormField, matTooltip is more or less independent.

Has somebody tried this or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it combining `matTooltip` and `matTooltipDisabled`:

```js
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Enter your email"
      [formControl]="email"
      [matTooltip]="getErrorMessage()"
      [matTooltipDisabled]="!email.invalid">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

The Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpnqm5

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice idea, but the tooltip is only visible while I hove over the input and disappears once i start editing.

Comment: According to [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#manually-calling-show-and-hide-), you can manually show or hide the tooltip. Maybe you can build a directive to force the tooltip to stay visible